# Encoutered error: get neighbors failed when query by using Nebula Graph database

Tags: nebula-graph

I encountered this error when I use nebula graph which is running by [docker-compose](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula-docker-compose). When this error show first time, it will always exist when you query the data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your memory is used up. Check the service status. Please check your memory left. You can check the following:

- Your space number
- The partition number of your space.
- The replica_factor of your space.